# Is Google Chrome effectively buggy in its handling of desktop DPI?

Tags: web-applications, browser, google-chrome

They appear to assume that "web designers assume a fixed 72DPI" (or something specific anyway). But desktop DPI usually depends on screen physical size.

When I visited [this site](http://forums.urbanterror.info), I noticed its fonts look tiny compared to other browsers.

After some [quick research](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=389f306a52817110&hl=en), I stumbled into Development advisories from Google Chrome that pin point to that issue: they assume DPI is a constant quantity. Is it effectively a bug?

--

This thread appears to be rich on the subject: [from google.com](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=679)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome definitely has some display bugs. 
Many times, HTML checkboxes become invisible (simplest test using gmail). On zooming in/out, they SOMETIMES come back into view. (never faced this issue in IE/FF).

Comment: Also check my post here. Another funny incident with Chrome and the workaound: http://janakspen.blogspot.com/2010/11/google-chrome-display-issues.html

Answer (score 0):

That site's fonts are small because they have `font-size: 70%;` and later `font-size: 85%;`. So now it's down to 69.5% of the original size. The badly written CSS is to blame, not Chrome.

If it bothers you that much, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>.

Comment: What should they do to fix it without breaking it for other browsers?

Comment: Write font sizes in pixels, not percentages.

Comment: Wow. I read everywhere ems and percentages should be used instead of pixel sizes... Now I'm really confused.

Comment: No, the site is to blame. And use pixels, not percentages.

Comment: That doesn't answer the previous person's remark, that he learned to do it the opposite way.

Comment: Well, how do you expect me to answer it...? There wasn't a question, and I replied with a correction.

Answer (score 0):

The fonts look the same to me in Chrome and Firefox / Safari / IE